# Generate running MAT from Quarter data

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have list of quarters in my db table as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpKS1.png)

I need to populate Running MAT based on above quarters. The expected records are as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6jXx.png)

Can you please help me to achieve this in SQL server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement or final result is not very clear for me.
On the other hand, if you can check below [SQL CTE query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18), I believe it can help you

I hope the result is as  you wish
There is a cross join between the quarters table and the CTE expression which transforms the quarter names into a new format

```
; with cte as (
select
    SUBSTRING(Period_Qtr,1,4) + ' MAT Q' + SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Period_Qtr),1,1) as p
from quarters
)
select * 
from cte, quarters
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. but it is not giving the expected result. 

For quarter data '2014 quarter 1' , '2014 quarter 2', '2014 quarter 3', '2014 quarter 4' 
the period_mat column value will be '2014 mat q4'. 

For quarter data  '2014 quarter 2', '2014 quarter 3', '2014 quarter 4', '2015 quarter 1' 
the period_mat column value will be '2015 mat q1'.  

'2014 quarter 3', '2014 quarter 4', '2015 quarter 1' , '2015 quarter 2' t
he period_mat column value will be  '2015 mat q2' and so on